# How to async stream a file from database to webclient without buffering

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I'm trying to async stream a file from sql server out to a web client using .net 4.5 and web api.

I'm using SqlDataReader.GetStream() to get a stream from the db. However, I'm not sure how to wire in the disposal/closing of the db connection when webapi is finished reading from the stream.

Any samples out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a wrapping stream that reads from the underlying stream until it is depleted, and then disposes of all associated resources (like the SqlConnection).

I'm not a WebAPI expert so there might be a more elegant way to do it. But this will work in any case with the standard WebAPI support for streams.

Comment: Marking this as the answer as I couldn't get the push stream content to work. I created a wrapping stream and set the content length to get this to work. Without the content length it would not work (with owin in IIS and selfhost)

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like following in Web API. Here I am using `PushStreamContent` to connect to database and retrieve the Sql stream. I then copy this sql stream to the response stream directly. In Web API, when you use PushStreamContent, the client would receive response in chunked transfer encoding because you are not setting the content-length  of the response. If this is fine for you, you could use the below example. Otherwise I will try to see if there are any other better ways to accomplish this.

NOTE: This is a quick example based on PushStreamContent and **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556234.aspx)** article on MSDN regarding retrieving binary data from sql server.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private const string connectionString = @"your connection string";

    [Route("{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetImage(int id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage();

        resp.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (responseStream, content, context) =>
        {
            await CopyBinaryValueToResponseStream(responseStream, id);
        });

        return resp;
    }

    // Application retrieving a large BLOB from SQL Server in .NET 4.5 using the new asynchronous capability
    private static async Task CopyBinaryValueToResponseStream(Stream responseStream, int imageId)
    {
        // PushStreamContent requires the responseStream to be closed
        // for signaling it that you have finished writing the response.
        using (responseStream)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [bindata] FROM [Streams] WHERE [id]=@id", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", imageId);

                    // The reader needs to be executed with the SequentialAccess behavior to enable network streaming
                    // Otherwise ReadAsync will buffer the entire BLOB into memory which can cause scalability issues or even OutOfMemoryExceptions
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                    {
                        if (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            if (!(await reader.IsDBNullAsync(0)))
                            {
                                using (Stream data = reader.GetStream(0))
                                {
                                    // Asynchronously copy the stream from the server to the response stream
                                    await data.CopyToAsync(responseStream);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }// close response stream
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying something along those lines but get this error: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Comment: Which version of Web API are you using? specifically which version of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` nuget package are you using?

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: you mean my action is not returning a Task?...no that is not required as I am doing the async based stuff in my PushStreamContent's async Func...I have made little modifications to the above code and tried it now and its working fine...could you share your implementation, wondering if there are any subtle differences causing the issue you are seeing?

Comment: I just haven't been able to get the above to work. I triple checked the code to no avail.
Tried the other answer's suggestion and works as long as I set the content length header

Comment: I know this is old, but how could you use this, but add more columns in your SQL query (such as [FileName], [MimeType], but still stream back the [bindata]... I would then use the [FileName] and [MimeType] to set response headers...

Comment: that's awesome thanks. Is there any way to do the same on Oracle Database. Tried the same approach but it seems not to work

Comment: It doesn't work if the app runs in classic mode - which it is my case. I got: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode. :-(