# C#/WebApi Filedownload from Database stream

Tags: c#, sql, streaming, blob

I have a .net server hosted with Owin/WebApi. I got a controller for downloading files. The files are stored as blob in the database. Currently, the blob is loaded into memory and then streamed to the client. That's working fine. However, I want to avoid to load the whole blob into memory on the server, because it can get huge.

What is the right way to do so? Do I need to save it to a file first?
Currently I'm working with an MS-SQL Database, but it should later also be working with Oracle.

I'm on .net 4.5.2.

**Update:**

I found a solution in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221805/1682946

PushStreamContent did the job!

Unfortunately, this is not working for OracleDataReader for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to async stream a file from database to webclient without buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220673/how-to-async-stream-a-file-from-database-to-webclient-without-buffering)

Comment: that's actually the thread I took the answer from ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20221805/1682946